# How to expand multiple columns in Smart Table of SAPUI5?

Tags: sapui5

I have smart table with multiple columns that need to be expanded

Currently I'm able to expand one column as follows:

```
onBeforeRebindTable: function (oEvent) {
            var oBindingParams = oEvent.getParameter("bindingParams");
            oBindingParams.parameters["expand"] = "expandableColumn1";
        }
```

However when I try to add two column names as an error:

```
onBeforeRebindTable: function (oEvent) {
            var oBindingParams = oEvent.getParameter("bindingParams");
            oBindingParams.parameters["expand"] = ["expandableColumn1", "expandableColumn2"];
        }
```

I get this error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: s.replace is not a function
    at e (encodeURL-dbg.js:59)
    at constructor.J.createCustomParams (ODataModel-dbg.js:2403)
    at new constructor (ODataListBinding-dbg.js:75)
    at constructor.J.bindList (ODataModel-dbg.js:1906)
    at f.p._bindAggregation (cdm.js:214)
    at f.t._bindAggregation (ListBase-dbg.js:658)
    at f.p.bindAggregation (cdm.js:214)
    at f.<anonymous> (cdm.js:216)
    at constructor.j1._reBindTable (SmartTable-dbg.js:2628)
    at f.b.fireEvent (cdm.js:197)
```

Cannot find much regarding this in the documentation. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out,

multiple fields have to be entered comma seperated in a single string in this way:

```
oBindingParams.parameters["expand"] = "expandableColumn1,expandableColumn2";
```